# ElGamal signatures systems

Tags: elgamal-encryption, elgamal-signature

Let $p$ prime number $q/p-1$ prime and $g\in (Z/pZ)^*$ element of order $q$.Also $a\in \{1,...,q-1\}$ the private key and $y\equiv g^a\pmod p$ the correspoding public key.For each of the following systems ElGamal give the verification(authentication) algorithm of signature $(r,s)$

1. $r\equiv g^k\pmod p$      ,$s\equiv k^{-1}(h(m)+2ar^2)\pmod q$
2. $r\equiv g^k\pmod p$,$s\equiv kh(m)+ar\pmod q$
3. $r\equiv g^{-k}\pmod p$,$s\equiv a^{-1}(kh(m)+r)\pmod q$

Can anyone give me any hints to solve this problem?

Comment: you're looking for the corresponding verification procedures / equations right?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: any ideas to solve it?

Comment: concerning 2): maybe: $r^{h(m)}\equiv g^s * (y^{r})^{-1} \pmod p$

Comment: how i can think for $2)$?

Comment: The general thought process should be: "Find some equation which is true if $s$ is generated correctly and that involves $h(m),r,s,y$"

Comment: SEJPM already gave you one solution. For the others: Just think about what could cancel each other out with the according $s$. Since the computation of $s$ is done mod $q$, you can be sure that the parts of $s$ are only used in the exponent.

Comment: for each occasion i will ''solve a system'' ?that will generate an equation of $r$?

Comment: Start by writing $g^s$ on one side of the equation. And then try to get the same term on the other side by using $g,k,h(m),a$ only. Keep in mind that the term $r$ is defined by the exercise, and $a$ is only known in the form $y=g^a$. There's not much more we can help you with, without giving you the solution directly. And that surely isn't the goal of this exercise.

Comment: when i found the equations, can i upload the, here to check if i am correct?